# CakePHP Convert MySQL DateTime to Unix Timestamp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have an issue with CakePHP's query builder trying to select a DATETIME field and using the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function.

This is my custom finder:

```
    public function findApi(Query $query, array $options) {
      $unixTimestamp = $query->func()->unix_timestamp(['sample_time' => 'identifier']);

      return $query->select([
                      'sample_time' => $unixTimestamp,
                      'min'         => 'min_psi',
                      'max'         => 'max_psi',
                    ])
                    ->where([
                      'machine_id' => $options['machine_id'],
                      'sample_time >=' => $options['start'],
                      'sample_time <=' => $options['end']
                    ]);
    }
```

But I keep getting a "failed to parse" warning when I try to get the result set and my sample time is **false**:

```
Warning (2): DateTimeImmutable::modify(): Failed to parse time string (1564618674) at position 8 (7): Unexpected character [CORE/src/Database/Type/DateTimeType.php, line 188]
Code Context

            if ($previousHandler) {
                return $previousHandler($code, $message, $file, $line, $context);
            }

$value = '1564618674'
$driver = object(Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql) {

    'connected' => true

}
$instance = object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

    'time' => '2019-10-23T17:01:38+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

}

Cake\Core\BasePlugin::{closure}() - ROOT/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/config/bootstrap.php, line 42
DateTimeImmutable::modify() - [internal], line ??
Cake\Database\Type\DateTimeType::toPHP() - CORE/src/Database/Type/DateTimeType.php, line 188
Cake\Database\FieldTypeConverter::__invoke() - CORE/src/Database/FieldTypeConverter.php, line 135
Cake\Database\Statement\CallbackStatement::fetch() - CORE/src/Database/Statement/CallbackStatement.php, line 59
Cake\ORM\ResultSet::_fetchResult() - CORE/src/ORM/ResultSet.php, line 487
Cake\ORM\ResultSet::valid() - CORE/src/ORM/ResultSet.php, line 277
Cake\ORM\ResultSet::first() - CORE/src/ORM/ResultSet.php, line 299
Cake\ORM\Query::first() - CORE/src/Datasource/QueryTrait.php, line 471
App\Controller\Api\WaterPressuresController::getJsonResults() - APP/Controller/Api/WaterPressuresController.php, line 64
App\Controller\Api\WaterPressuresController::index() - APP/Controller/Api/WaterPressuresController.php, line 22
Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 610
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php, line 120
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php, line 94
Cake\Http\BaseApplication::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/BaseApplication.php, line 235
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php, line 162

/src/Controller/Api/WaterPressuresController.php (line 66)

[
    'sample_time' => false,
    'min_val' => (int) 75,
    'max_val' => (int) 91
]
```

It looks like CakePHP is trying to convert the field with FieldTypeConverter. How do I prevent the conversion so I can use the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function and get my results as an integer instead of a datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting a unix timestamp for an existing column, which is of some sort of date/time type, but CakePHP's date/time type converter doesn't support unix timestamps, it expects date/time-ish values in formats like `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

You can workaround this by simply using a different alias in the select list, eg something like:

```
'sample_timestamp' => $unixTimestamp,
```

or by remapping the type for the query:

```
$query->getSelectTypeMap()->addDefaults(['sample_time' => 'integer']);
```

I'd suggest that you also look into converting the value on PHP level when it's actually needed, the date/time objects that the ORM creates for your date/time-ish column has a `getTimestamp()` method, so you could do:

```
$entity->sample_time->getTimestamp()
```